# Overlapping in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have one `RelativeLayout` which contains 2 linearlayouts, one should always be aligned with bottom (for log out purpose.) and the other starts from top and contains 2 viewstubs. These two viewstubs have different heights any only one of them will be visible at same time.

My problem is if I make top linearlayout align top and bottom linearlayout align bottom, contents overlap if viewstubs height is bigger.

I can not make them above and below of any as if the viewstubs height is smaller views start not from the corners.

How can I avoid them from overlapping?

Comment: Why can't you wrap the top and bottom LinearLayouts in another LinearLayout, rather than a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Post some code what you're trying then I'll fix it.

Comment: I think you should wrap your view stub or LinearLayout in a ScrollView and set it's fillViewPort attribute to true.

Comment: Posting code will help much for getting answer.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 3 LinearLayouts set the center layout as it is which you have done above/below
and add that centered layout into scroll view
after it still your problem do not solve so just let me know :) Happy coding.

Comment: And yes you need to take RelativeLayout as your main layout of an .xml

Answer (score 0):

you don't say anything about position of two subviews. So, I mean each view has with = 1/2 screen. Just try my solution.

abc.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:background="#116611">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#116611"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_insideScroll1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#118811"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--Bottom LinearLayout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#113311"
        android:layout_weight="2">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and for test this layout:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
        LinearLayout ll_insideScroll1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_insideScroll1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 50;i++){
            TextView v = new TextView(this);
            v.setText("TextView "+i);
            ll_insideScroll1.addView(v,i);
        }
    }
```