# How to make RelativeLayout to scroll when in Portrait orientation mode

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have these 2 images for Land and Portrait mode orientation (Image 1 for Landscape mode, Image 2 for portrait mode, when I write when in Landscape mode and turn the orientation to portrait it does show the full writing i made in Landscape, therefore I want to make it scrollable when the orientation switches to portrait so it can show the full writing i made while it was in Landscape mode.

sorry i don't have up to 10reputations to post the image here directly:-
   image 1: http://testimage/1.png
   image 2: http://testimage/2.png

Below is the code I use when the orientation is in landscape,FYI: I also created a Layout-Land when in Landsacpe mode

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/color12" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include layout="@layout/menu_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/menu_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menus" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layouts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_note"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblDate"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#222222"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblTime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblTotal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="#222222"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title" />
            </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />
      </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/menu_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/attach_view"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/attachment_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/aImage"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Attachment"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#222222" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/aImage"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_attachment" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bot_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/attach_view"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lblRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tool_left"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lblLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tool_right"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_text_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                layout="@layout/tool_text_button_layout"
                android:padding="13dp" />

            <!--
             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tool_type_text" />
            -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tool_thumbs" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_sync"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sync"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_attachment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email_attachment_small"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".20"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_italics"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".20"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_italics"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_underline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".20"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_underline"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_mode"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menus"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
     </ListView>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/attach_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:text="Add Image"
                android:textColor="#222222" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Audio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:text="Add Audio"
                android:textColor="#222222" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:text="Add Video"
                android:textColor="#222222" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:width="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btncancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Exit"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:width="100dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the selection in the xml that has the yellow writing background

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layouts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try to use Scroll view

Comment: @koutuk, how n where in my code should i use it, i will appreciate an edit to my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264007/overlapping-in-relativelayout/30273007#30273007 try this my answer hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Relative Layout has no orientation

LINK : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

However you can make a scrollable view

[How to implement HorizontalScrollView like Gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery)

Comment: how do I implement this HorizontalScrollView using what I have, or do I have to change it

Comment: Do follow the link given, horizontal scrollView like gallery.


More example : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/